# HTML, Floating, Small Problem, Seems Simple

Tags: html, css-float

If you look at my [Jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4Eetc/), the float seems to disregard the title text that is to the left of the floated element. My goal is to make the floated element not overlap the title text and to stop once it reaches the end of the div which is the title text

My questions, is this possible?
I just do not want it to overlap the element which is to the left of the floated element.
Thanks in advance for the advice, suggestions, etc.

[Jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/4Eetc/)

Comment: I'm a little confused about what the finished result should look like. Could you elaborate?  A quick image would help.

Comment: I want the advertisment_one div to float to the right of the page, but I do not want it to overlap the title div when the browser screen gets smaller. It seems to ignore the title div and just overlap it. I want it to not overlap the title div and just stop once the title div reaches it's minimum width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `Position: Relative` from your `#advertisement_1` div, and in the HTML put it above the title div.

Below is an updated JSFiddle with it working, you may need to adjust the "top" value in your CSS for the advert box if it needs to be different to what is in the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/f5j2z/

Comment: I think you added the wrong link. That link seems to have identical content to the link in the question.

Comment: @thirtydot - Thanks, I've never used jsfiddle before, and didn't realise you had to hit the "update" button!

Comment: in order to have it not wrap up into the title div, I would use some property such as overlfow:none; or something along those lines, right?

Comment: @RPM - If you want to move the advertisement up the page, you can just re-use the `top:-310px;` css. I had to remove it to demonstrate the solution in the fiddle. If you need to make it a specific size (so that it doesn't overlap the title, for example), you can simply set the height in CSS, and use `overflow:none;` to make sure that extra content inside doesn't make the div bigger. Does that help?

Comment: Your answers have helped. But, ultimately what I want to do is: have the advertisment float to right of the page, but if the screen is resized i want to the advertisment to move all the way to the left where there is room and have it not overlap the title div. Basically I do not want it to overlap, I'm gonna try the overflow:none property